# If x, y, and z are positive numbers such that $3x < 2y < 4z$, which of the following statements could be true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is more or less a question about how many cases I should be trying in general on the quantitative section of the GRE.

I got this question wrong and it is because I did not try enough cases, so I was wondering if anyone has any tips on how to see that a given condition may be true without trying 5 different cases.

Question:

If x, y, and z are positive numbers such that $3x < 2y < 4z$, which of the following statements could be true? Indicate all such statements.

a. $x=y$

b. $y=z$

c. $y>z$

d. $x>z$

---

My work:

For a)

$x=2, y=2, z=3$

$3x=6, 2y=4, 4z=12$

$6<4<12$ is false.

a) cannot be true.

For b)

$x=1, y=4, z=4$

$3x=3, 2y=8, 4z=16$

$3<8<16$ is true.

b) can be true.

For c)

$x=1, y=4, z=3$

$3x=3, 2y=8, 4z=12$

$3<8<12$ is true.

c) can be true.

Now d) was the reason for missing this question. I plugged in one case as I did with a) yet there is in fact a threshold such that this works.

For example:

$x=7, y=11, z=6$

$3x=21, 2y=22, 4z=24$

$21<22<24$ is true.

d) can be true.

However, during the practice test (this was the last question I was crunched for time and had to the second to last because this one looked easier) I only plugged in one case and it didn't work so I quit.

Tips?

Comment: It seems like you can save more time by excluding the third variable in each of your tests. You can always take one to go to a very large value or very small value, depending on what you want

Comment: Don't plug in numbers: think conceptually. For example,  to decide whether $y>z$ could be true, focus on $y$ and $z$. The given statement implies $y<2z$, and this is all we know about how $y$ and $z$ compare. This just means $y$ is less than twice $z$. So of course it's possible that $y$ could be more than $z$, because there are numbers between $z$ and $2z$.

Comment: Similarly, the statement implies $x<(4/3)z$. So all we know is that $x$ is smaller than a number bigger than $z$. So of course $x$ could be bigger than $z$. (Keep in mind the assumption that all numbers are positive is important here.)

Comment: Didn't see these before marking the best answer! Thank you both for the comments, the problem is much more clear with both suggestions! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the inequality to three separate inequalities:

$$(1)\quad x<\dfrac{2}{3}y$$

$$(2)\quad y<2z$$

$$(3)\quad x<\dfrac{4}{3}z$$

Now we conclude easily

(a) false by (1)

(b) true by (2) since $z=y<2z$ still holds.

(c) true by (2) since $z<1.5z=y<2z$ is possible

(d) true by (3) since $z<1.1z=x<\dfrac{4}{3}z$ is possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very clear, thorough, and concise!

Answer (score 2):

Your work for part (a) is useless.  It is given that $x, y, z$ *always* satisfy $3x < 2 y < 4 z$.  If you choose $x,y,z$ that violate that constraint, they are not relevant to the problem.

Part (a): $x < \frac{2}{3}y$, so $x$ is never as large as $y$, so $x \neq y$ always.

For parts (b) and (c), you made valid choices of $x,y,z$, so have these answers.

For part (d), $3x<4z$ is the given relation (that is, $x < \frac{4}{3}z$) and $x>z$ can be satisfied if $z < x < \frac{4}{3} z$, which is easy to arrange for large enough $z$.  You also require a multiple of $2$, $2y$, between $3x$ and $4z$, so you may have to go a little bigger.

In a bit more detail on (d): $z < x < \frac{4}{3} z$, so look at multiples of $3$ for $z$ so I don't have to waste time on that fraction.  $z=3$ is too small because there's no room for $x$ between $3$ and $4$.  $z = 6$ forces $x = 7$.  Is there an even number between $21$ and $24$?  Yes, $22$, so $y=11$.

Comment: Thank you so much this is so much clearer! I gave the answer to @InterstellarProbe because i) their answer is shorter and more likely for me to remember the next time I encounter a similar problem, ii) they answered first, and iii) they have less points under their profile name so they could use the answer points:D

Comment: @LopeyTall : You can accept any answer you like.  As a detail, InterstellarProbe did not answer first.

Comment: Oh gosh your right, I'm blind!  haha :) Thanks again mate!:)

Answer (score 0):

In a), you try *one* specific set of numbers only. So at best you show that a)  is *sometimes* false. This does not exclude the possibility that it is *sometimes* true. Instead, if $x,y,z$ are positive and $3x<2y<4z$, then 
$$ 3x<2y<2y+y=3y$$
and hence $x<y$ (and not $x=y$). We see that a) is *always* false and *never* true* under the given assumptions.

Of course ouy are right that for the three cases, where one has to show that the asked statement *can* be true, a single specific example suffices. However, it does not suffice to plug in just any valid triple - after all, it need not be (and is not) the case that the statement is *always* true. Thus it suffices to plug in one set of numbers, but it has to be a smartly chosen one. In other words, you have to contemplate the given conditions and the target property as to what "obstacles" there might be for the target property and if these obstables can be shown to always be there or if they disappear in certain achievable situations ...